# View not found Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view

I want to add a view to my email. I already set the namespace in my provider but it cannot be found

My map structure is:

`src-> Domain -> Quotation -> views-> BookedMail.php`

`src-> Domain -> Quotation -> QuotationController.php`

`src-> Providers`

The Function being called (from the controller from the Quotation dir)

```
    Mail::send('Quotation::BookedMail', [], function ($message) use ($request) {
        $message->to($request['email'], '')->subject('Loslijst ' . date('d-m-Y'));
    });
```

The setting of the namespace ( in the Providers dir )

```
$this->loadViewsFrom('../Domain/Quotation/views','Quotation');
```

the error is `View [BookedMail] not found`

Comment: Remove the beginning slash from `loadViewsFrom`. That will attempt to load it from the server root.

Comment: @aynber that did not fix the error but thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to load the views from the server root since your path is starting with a `/`.

You could use the [app_path](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/helpers#method-app-path) helper instead by changing it to:

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(app_path('Domain/Quotation/views'), 'Quotation');
```

However, if you want to use relative path, you could do it like this:

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../Domain/Quotation/views', 'Quotation');
```

**Note:** If you are wondering why your [blade directives](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade) are not working, you should your view to `.blade.php` instead of `.php`.

Comment: this is in a submudle (in the vendor dir) of the main app. will app_path pick the main from the module or the main app?

Comment: @Nick Is it a package that you are developing?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typo: you're calling `Quotation::BookedMail` where your view file is named `BookedEmail`.

EDIT: this was a typo on the question itself rather than in the project, please disregard this answer

Comment: sorry that was a mistype on my part. the file is named BookedMail